# can I implement google login and in-app purchase for my desktop application?

Tags: java, libgdx, in-app-purchase, google-signin

I'm making a game using libGDX (java), and successfully implements google login and in-app purchase for my android game.

Later, I want to apply them to my desktop game, too.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `Google Sign-In` is available only for these platform `ANDROID`, `iOS`, `WEB`, `TVS`. However by using swing component with `WEB Google-Sign-In`, you can login your user on your desktop application.

Currently we've [gdx-pay](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay), cross-platform API for InApp purchasing but no implementation for desktop yet. Check this [thread](https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=19263), It seems to be an implementation of in-app purchase for desktop game.